# Replacing empty column value depending on other columns value in unix

Tags: unix, awk, replace, command

I have a comma separated dat file which has some empty values in 2nd column. I have to replace empty values of only those rows which has value starting with "BL" in 7th column.

I am new to unix. I have thought of using awk command and fetch all these rows using

```
awk -F, '$7 ~ /^"BL*/ && $2 ~ /^"[ ]*"$/ {print $0 > temp.dat} input.dat
```

But still I am confused how to replace values. Also I have to keep all other data in the file. Please suggest what command I should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the value of the 2nd column to something else, you simply use `$2="<something else>"`.

Here is an example:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{if($7~/^BL/ && $2==""){$2="foo"}print;}' file
```

Comment: missing a `;` between `}` and `print`?

Comment: No, it's not required. Even the `;` after `print` is not required.

Comment: ah, ok... but still, I would add one to clearly separate the print from the "if/then" preceding it... so +1 as you answer the OP's question, but i still regret that omission. Readability is important.

Comment: In this case the closing brace (`}`) terminates the if-statement. You don't need a `;` after the `}` because that would be an empty statement which would get executed and add extra overhead unnecessarily.

Comment: then you should update the question and add an extract from your input file.

Comment: Hey It worked. Thanks for this. But I have one more question. I have to read value of column 2 for which column 7 has value starting with "BL" and column 2 is not empty. I know I can do it using the same command but I want to stop the search when 1st row is found. please suggest.

Comment: You can use `exit` to stop `awk` as soon as the first row is found. Here is an example command: `awk -F, -vOFS=, '{if($7~/^BL/ && $2!=""){print $0 " <---Found";exit}print;}' file`

Comment: Please help me in one more thing. The String which I have to use for replacement i.e. "foo" is stored in a variable $var is "Mgr"(with quotes). Now how to use this. When I am using it, it gives me error Field $() is not correct. I believe as variable is passed inside quotes of awk command, this is not working.

Comment: To pass a shell variable `$var` into `awk`, you need to use the `-v` option. Here is an example: `awk -F, -vOFS=, -v myVar="$var" '{if($7~/^BL/ && $2==""){$2=myVar}print;}' file`

Comment: It worked. :-) I have tried that before, but I appended it with first -v you have used. I still didn't understand What is first -v is for?

Comment: -v sets a single Awk variable before running the program. It's prominent in the man page.